# Slim external route file error

Tags: file, routes, slim

Im starting to work with Slim (3.8.1). I am playing with the tickets sample.

Since I am thinking of a larger application I want the have my routes in separate files. But when I include the route file in my index.php I am getting this error:

*"Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Closure::{closure}() must be an instance of Request, instance of Slim\Http\Request given"*

This is my route file (simple copy of what was in index.php before, enclosed in php tags):

```
<?php
$app->get('/tickets', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
   $this->logger->addInfo("Ticket list");
   $mapper = new TicketMapper($this->db);
   $tickets = $mapper->getTickets();

   $response = $this->view->render($response, "tickets.phtml", ["tickets" => $tickets, "router" => $this->router]);
   return $response;
});
?>
```

In my index.php file I have this instead now:

```
require '../routes/tickets.php';
```

Do I have to register the path of the route files somehow?

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the following works in the external route file:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) 
{
    $response = $this->view->render($response, "home.phtml");
    return $response;
});
?>
```